# Anydesk on Ubuntu does not save Unattended Access Security Setting

Tags: 19.10, remote-access, anydesk

I tried to enable unattended access by:

1. Run Anydesk as root user: `sudo anydesk`
2. Go to Settings -> Security
3. Check **Enable unattended access** checkbox
4. Set password and click OK button
   [image: Anydesk unattended access password setting]

But after OK button clicking Unattended Access settings have not been changed:

[image: Anydesk settings after OK button clicking]

Also, connecting to this PC remotely shows a message that connection should be accepted on the other side.

Is there another way I could configure unattended access in ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. I've edited anydesk config file:

   `sudo vi /etc/anydesk/system.conf`

   changing value of one of its parameters from 0 to 1:

   `ad.security.interactive_access=1`
2. Opened Anydesk by unprivileged user
3. Enabled unattended access and set password

As a result, it became enabled:

[image: Enabled unattended access picture]

**Updated:**
In current Anydesk 5.5.5 version run in terminal:

```
$ anydesk-global-settings
```

Then enter your current user password and set Unattended access. Now it saves it.

Comment: sudo anydesk-global-settings worked for me